# Is it considered 'ok' to put data in a header file?

Tags: c, header

Let's say I'm creating a simple library called plots in C. Let's say I have a couple functions such as `PlotFunction()`, `SetTitle()`, `SetScale()`, etc. Let's also say I want to provide some basic plots such as `Triangle`, `Rectangle`, etc which are resource files. I'm thinking these resources would be held as arrays (`e.g. triangle[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0}`)

Would this be an example where it is okay to have data included in a header file? Typically I think of header files be reserved for function prototypes, but this seems like an instance where it would be appropriate to include variables/structures in a header.

Is this considered bad practice? Are there better alternatives to this?

Comment: Generally data can be part of a source file with external linkage, so there's no advantage to putting it into a header file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not put such data in your header file.  Instead:

```
extern const int triangle[];
extern const size_t triangle_size;
```

Then in a source (.c) file:

```
const int triangle[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0};
const size_t triangle_size = sizeof(triangle) / sizeof(triangle[0]);
```

This way the data only gets compiled and linked once.

---

However, if you really need to use this data to actually initialize other variables efficiently, you may consider this:

```
#define TRIANGLE {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0}
```

Then users can do:

```
int shape[] = TRIANGLE;
```

A famous example like this in the wild is [PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.htm).

Comment: The other advantage of doing it this way is that you can change the data without causing a full rebuild.  Changes to headers cause rebuilds in all the files in which they are included.